# Relation that is only symmetric, reflexive, antisymmetric or transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

> What could be a possible example of a relation that's symm, reflex, antisymm, transitive?

I am working on practice problems on the unit about Sets and Relations.
The question asks me to give a example of a relation that is symm, reflexi, antisym, and transitive. I don't seem to find any possible example that suits this conditions.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by making sure that it’s not transitive. Let $R$ be the relation, and suppose that $a\,R\,b$, where $a\ne b$. Symmetry will require that $b\,R\,a$, so you’ll have to have $a\,R\,b\,R\,a$; transitivity would tell you that $a\,R\,a$, so if you make sure that $a\,\not R\,a$, you’ll kill two birds with one stone by ensuring both that $R$ is not transitive and that $R$ is not reflexive. That leaves just antisymmetry to deal with.

At this point you have a set $A=\{a,b\}$ and a relation $R=\{\langle a,b\rangle,\langle b,a\rangle\}$ on $A$. Is this $R$ antisymmetric? If it’s not, you’re done. If it is, can you add something to it (and possible to $A$) to make kill off antisymmetry?

Comment: @johnmalko: Yes, it is, and $a\,\not R\,a$ is $\langle a,a\rangle\notin R$; it’s by analogy with such familiar notations as $<$ and $\not\le$. You’re welcome!

Comment: @johnmalko: No, I specified that $a$ and $b$ are distinct objects: $a\ne b$. Therefore $R$ is ... ?

Comment: oops so it is not antisymmetric.... done!! thank u so much

Comment: @johnmalko: Now you’ve got it. You’re very welcome.

Comment: @johnmalko: In this case it’s both. Transitivity tells you that if $\langle a,b\rangle,\langle b,c\rangle\in R$, then $\langle a,c\rangle\in R$. If, as in this case, $c$ happens to be $a$, the conclusion is that $\langle a,a\rangle\in R$.

Comment: @johnmalko: Since $a$ is definitely equal to $a$, I think that you meant ‘since I said that $a\,\not r\,a$’; if so, yes, you’re right.

Comment: @johnmalko: The relation would be the $R$ of my answer, with the pairs $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle b,a\rangle$ and no others. (You need both for symmetry.) If you want to make it clearer that $a\ne b$, replace them by $0$ and $1$, say.

Answer (score 2):

Integers that add up to an odd number.